# MAAS can't apt update

Tags: apt, maas

I'm setting up MAAS for our workstations and it's going great! I've deployed a test VM with it. The only thing that doesn't work is apt.

I can't perform an `apt update`.  It looks for `172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal` and I have no idea where it's getting it from.

This is the full output:

```
~# apt update
Err:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
  Could not resolve '172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal'
Err:2 http://aptly bionic InRelease            
  Could not resolve '172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal'
Err:3 http://aptly bionic-updates InRelease    
  Could not resolve '172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal'
Err:4 http://aptly bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve '172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
W: Failed to fetch http://aptly/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve '172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal'
W: Failed to fetch http://aptly/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve '172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal'
W: Failed to fetch http://aptly/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve '172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal'
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve '172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
# Aptly 
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] http://aptly/ bionic main universe 
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] http://aptly/ bionic-updates main universe
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64] http://aptly/ bionic-security main universe
```

I also tried it with the default `sources.list` but it had the same error.

The `/etc/resolv.conf` file just points to my DNS server.

No matter what I put in my `sources.list` file it keeps complaining about `172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal`. Why is it looking for `172-16-0-0--16.maas-internal`?  What is it? Can i go around it? Do I have to setup a new DNS record? How can I have apt working?

Huge thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

had to delete `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy`

Comment: while it does the trick, this is not the best way to procedure, because there are other services that will be configured to use MAAS rack controller as a proxy; the suitable solution is the configure the network correctly for the network used to comissioning/deployment; adding the DNS and gateway shall solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have edited your network configs. If you have edited please try these steps:

1. You need to set MAAS IP address as the DNS of all your node you are trying to `apt update`.

##### Example

```
    enp3:
      match:
        macaddress: 62:34:0f:91:1b:e2
      addresses:
       - 172.168.0.12/24
      gateway4: 172.168.0.10
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 172.168.0.16 #<<<< IP OF THE MAAS INTERFACE #
      set-name: enp3
```

2. Go to the MAAS Subnet and set the correct DNS Names. See attached screenshot.
   [image]
3. Lastly, for the changes to take place, restart your maas network `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd` and your node or reboot.